# google and facebook login with ionic platform browser

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic3

I'm Developing Hybrid app using ionic-3 framework. Now i want to add Google and Facebook login in ionic-3 platform browser. Ionic native plugin is not working on platform browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate social login link Facebook by generating API key.[Please refer this link](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework) will give you brief about facebook login in ionic application.
for more details please refer ionic forum link [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-implement-log-in-with-facebook-and-google-in-an-ionic-app/11103/18)